# Change byte[] to MediaElement Source in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt video in xamarin. Decryption returns video as an array of bytes. How can I play it as mediaElement source?!!

Comment: Write it to a file

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] mediaData = {your data};
string mediaUrl = string.Format($"data:video/mp4;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(mediaData)}");
mediaElement.Source = MediaSource.FromUri(mediaUrl);
```